# Quartz.net scheduler is not working

Tags: cron, quartz.net

I'm using Quartz.net to set up a scheduler that send out email everyday at 15.59 o'clock.
And this what I used:

```
0 59 15 * * ?
```

but it never fired.

To find out whether my database consists data that will fire the scheduler, I used

```
0 0/1 * * * ?
```

that will fire every minute, and it works just fine.

Is there anything wrong with my cron for daily job?

Comment: Your cron expression looks correct to me. Does it work for other specified times, ie not a repeating one?

Answer (score 0):

Your cron expression should be : `0 59 15 1/1 * ? *`.
This will run your cron job everyday at 15:59. Visit [cronmaker](http://cronmaker.com/) to generate more such cron expressions.

Comment: The askers cron expession looks correct. '*' for the day of month field will work just as well as '1/1'.  The final year field is optional.